# loading a url picture

Tags: swift

I'm new to IOS development and I'm trying to load an image from a URL, I understand there are some changes between the swift versions.
for some reason I get **imageData = nil** and I'm not sure why..

```
 private func fetchImage() 
 {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/blog_1280x720.png")
    if  let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL){
            image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check :

```
private func fetchImage() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/blog_1280x720.png")!
    let task = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error Occurred: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        else {
            if let imageData = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            } else {
                print("Image file is currupted")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong initializer of `URL`. That one is for filesystem URLs, not for network URLs. This is the working version of your function:

```
private func fetchImage(){
    if let url = URL(string: "https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/blog_1280x720.png"), let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
       image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

However, you should completely rewrite your function, because `Data(contentsOf:)` is a synchronous method and hence should only be used to retrieve local files, not files from the internet.

```
func fetchImage(from url:URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?)->Void){
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil, let data = data else {
            completion(nil);return
        }
        completion(UIImage(data: data))
    }).resume()
}

fetchImage(from: URL(string: "https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/blog_1280x720.png")!, completion: {image in
    if let image = image {
        //use the image
    } else {
        //an error occured and the image couldn't be retrieved
    }
})
```

Comment: besides the fact that the user is using the wrong URL initializer he also needs to allow arbitrary load in the info plist NSAppTransportSecurity or add the exception domains

Comment: The URL is https, so I don't see a reason why that would be needed.